# How can one prove that the set of reflexive relation on $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm seeking for a proof that the set $S$ of a reflexive relations over $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable. It would be also helpful if someone could give me some general method for finding an injective or surjective function that proves this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each subset $A$ of $\Bbb N$ of size greater than $1$, consider the relation $\mathcal{R}_A = \{(x,y)\in \Bbb N\times \Bbb N~:~x=y\vee (x\in A\wedge y\in A)\}$

That is to say, given a subset $A$, let everything in $A$ be related to everything else inside of $A$ and everything outside of $A$ be related only to themselves.

It is clear that each subset of $A$ defines a unique such relation and that each relation defined this way is reflexive.

It is clear then there are at least as many such relations as there are subsets of $\Bbb N$ which is known to be uncountable.

Comment: could you maybe formalise this by giving an injective or surjective function? That would probably be somehow more intuitive for me... Thanks however!

Comment: Consider an injective function from $2^{\Bbb N}$ to the set of reflexive relations over $\Bbb N$ given by $A\mapsto \mathcal{R}_A$ where $\mathcal{R}_A$ is as defined above.

Comment: Small mistake in what I wrote., in the event that $|A|=|B|\leq 1$ you'd have $\mathcal{R}_A=\mathcal{R}_B=1_\Bbb N$, the identity relation on $\Bbb N$.  Insisting we look only at subsets of $\Bbb N$ whose size is strictly greater than $1$ fixes this however without largely impacting the flavor of the proof.  The cardinality of subsets of $\Bbb N$ of size strictly greater than $1$ is easily shown to also be uncountable.

Comment: @JMoravitz Maybe I'm missing something. Aren't $\mathcal{R}_A$ and $\mathcal{R}_B$ distinct for $A \neq B$, no matter the size of $A$ and $B$? For example, if $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$, we have $\mathcal{R}_A = \{(1,1)\}$ and $\mathcal{R}_B = \{(2,2)\}$, which are not the same.

Comment: @Charles yes, you are missing something, namely the first part of the condition that we also include all pairs of identical elements from outside of $A$ as well

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the clarification. I was thinking it could be reflexive without that stipulation, but of course it can't be. We at least need the diagonal.